# How do I properly overwrite entries in MySQL(MariaDB database) with exported file?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

If that makes a difference, here are my server data:
**SQL version:** 10.3.35-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
**Database tool:** phpMyAdmin 4.9.7

I have a table called `phpbb_posts`. It's a huge table with 17 949 entries, with the primary key named post_id, reaching 46302.

I also have a small plaintext *.sql file which holds only a small number of these entries, 749 of those. It's a typical exported file from phpMyAdmin that got various edits. What I want to do now, is to replace the entries on the database with the ones from the file, **without changing the primary key** or any duplicates.

For the sake of simplicity I made a smaller version of the file with just two entries in there if some other data in there has meaning. I just removed most of the entries themselves, schema is not changed:
https://pastebin.com/ctnqKgkM

The database already holds posts with ID 46182 and 46187 (and many many more).

I know there is a possibility to just do this:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (column_names)  
VALUES (data)  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE   
column1 = expression, column2 = expression…;
```

and I've used that sometimes, but completely rewriting the export.sql file manually with the column1=value, column2=value etc. is not an option, it holds hundreds of entries and it would take me dozens of hours to do that.

Is there any other option to do the trick?

Comment: Are you familiar with `REPLACE INTO`?

Comment: @barrycarter I've used `REPLACE` often but didn't hear about `REPLACE INTO`, no :o

Comment: Look into it-- it's vastly different from the string REPLACE command

Comment: @barrycarter Damn, I feel super dumb now :o I don't know why many google queries like "insert into replace if duplicate" never returned this to me. Thank you, I think it's what I'm looking for, testing right now.